# Android ListView smooth navigation while images from SDCard

Tags: android, listview

I saw a lot of implementations of smooth downloading images from web and showing them in listView with cache. Now I have the following situation: I'm storing images to SDCard and sometimes my listView shows them instead of images from web resource. In this case navigation in listView is not smooth. Do you know any good implementation of listView with image from sdCard?

Comment: Did you try Fedor's Lazyloading?

Comment: [Showing images from SDCard that smooth the scroll](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/android-custom-gallery-and-instant-upload-project/)

Comment: Well, I don`t know actually, can you post a link to it?

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading is the answer!
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html
Just ignore the the sections for downloading, but idea is the same!

Then check this code :
[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)

Comment: I did multithreading. Navigation became smooth but pictures changing very often while navigation. I don`t know. I need an example of smooth listView from with picture SDCard